# How to resolve "Connection Refused" from .NET HttpClient when URL works fine from browser

Tags: rest, xamarin

This is Xamarin app which is accessing the www.geonames.org site.  When I run it, it generates a System.Net.WebException "Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused)".  However, if I take the url produced in this method and paste it into a browser on the simulator, it works fine and returns the correct JSON.

```
    public async Task GetWeatherAsync(double longitude, double latitude, string username)
    {
        var url = string.Format("http://api.geonames.org/findNearByWeatherJSON?lat={0}&lng={1}&username={2}", latitude, longitude, username);

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);

        try
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var JsonResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var weather = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherResult>(JsonResult);

                SetValues(weather);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(response.RequestMessage);
            }
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: iOS or Android?

Comment: In my side in the Portable code. It can get the json file from server with no exception using same code. check your network env?

Comment: @SushiHangover It is Xamarin.Forms so this was in the PCL.  It happened for both platforms.

Comment: @MikeMa Yep, I thought of that last night so I tried it from outside the company network and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add a `HttpClientHandler` with the appropriate proxy settings. Instantiate an instance of `IWebProxy`:

```
public class WebProxy : IWebProxy
{
    public ICredentials Credentials { get; set; }

    private readonly Uri _proxyUri;
    public WebProxy(string proxyString)
    {
        _proxyUri = new Uri(proxyString);
    }

    public WebProxy(Uri proxyUri)
    {
        _proxyUri = proxyUri;
    }

    public Uri GetProxy(Uri destination)
    {
        return _proxyUri;
    }

    public bool IsBypassed(Uri host)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then instantiate the `HttpClient` with a handler that uses the proxy:

```
NetworkCredential proxyCreds = new NetworkCredential(
    ProxyConfig.Username, ProxyConfig.Password);

WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(ProxyConfig.Url)
{
    Credentials = proxyCreds
};

HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    PreAuthenticate = true,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Proxy = proxy
};

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
```